# Why does the argument ioNumBytes of AudioFileReadPacketData cause a crash?

Tags: ios, core-audio, exc-bad-access, audioqueue

I have got something really strange (at least for me but I am a noob).

```
UInt32 numBytesReadFromFile;
OSStatus err = AudioFileReadPacketData(
                                    audioFile, // The audio file whose audio packets you want to read.
                                    NO, // is cache set?
                                    &numBytesReadFromFile, // On output, the number of bytes of audio data that were read from the audio file.
                                    (AudioStreamPacketDescription *)_packetDescriptions, // array of packet descriptions of data that was read from the audio file (for CBR null)
                                    currentPacket, // the next packet to be read into buffer
                                    &numPackets, // number of actually read buffers
                                    _audioQueueBuffer->mAudioData
                                    );
```

AudioFileReadPacketData reads data from an audio file and places it in a buffer.

So my question is about the argument numBytesReadFromFile. [Apple writes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/AQPlayback/PlayingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005343-CH3-SW2)

> numBytesReadFromFile: On output, the number of bytes of audio data that were read from the audio file.

So far so good. Apple declares numBytesReadFromFile like in the example code above but for me this line of code crashes! I get an EXC BAD ACCESS.

```
UInt32 numBytesReadFromFile;
```

I need to declare numBytesReadFromFile like this and everything works fine:

```
UInt32 numBytesReadFromFile = 2048; // 2048 = size of my buffer
```

However this crashes too

```
UInt32 numBytesReadFromFile = 12
UInt32 numBytesReadFromFile = sizeof(UInt32)
```

but this does not

```
UInt32 numBytesReadFromFile = 1021; // a random number
```

I am not a very experienced C programmer but as far as I know I reserve some memory by declaring numBytesReadFromFile and the method audiofilereadpacketdata writes its data to the address of the variable. Please correct me if I am wrong.

So why does it crash? I think I haven't fixed the real problem.

My assumption is that I have some kind of a multithreading issue. When i prepare the queue I call AudioFileReadPacketData on the main thread and declaring

```
UInt32 numBytesReadFromFile;
```

works fine. I start playing the audio and a callback is invoked which calls AudioFilereadPacketData on an internal background thread of audio queue and the error described above occurs. If my assumption is right, can someone explain me the issue a bit more in detail as I am not experienced in multithreading.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post more code.  What is `ioNumBytes` initially?  Does it match your buffer size?

Comment: There is no more code. Everything is set up for AudioFileReadDataPack. Only numBytesReadFromFile needs to be declared and this is done right before AudioFileReadDataPack is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter `ioNumBytes` to `AudioFileReadPacketData` is an in/out parameter.  The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioFileConvertRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioFileReadPacketData) says:

> On input, the size of the outBuffer parameter, in bytes. On output,
>   the number of bytes actually read.
>
> You will see a difference in the input and output values if the byte
>   size for the number of packets you request in the ioNumPackets
>   parameter is smaller than the buffer size you pass in the outBuffer
>   parameter. In this case, the output value for this parameter is
>   smaller than its input value.

The value when the function is called determines how much data will be written to your buffer.  If the code you posted is correct, `numBytesReadFromFile` is never initialized to the size of `_audioQueueBuffer->mAudioData` and the program crashes because it attempts to write an undetermined amount of data to `_audioQueueBuffer->mAudioData`.  Try setting the parameter before the function call:

```
UInt32 numBytesReadFromFile = _audioQueueBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize;
OSStatus err = AudioFileReadPacketData(
                                    audioFile, // The audio file whose audio packets you want to read.
                                    NO, // is cache set?
                                    &numBytesReadFromFile, // On output, the number of bytes of audio data that were read from the audio file.
                                    (AudioStreamPacketDescription *)_packetDescriptions, // array of packet descriptions of data that was read from the audio file (for CBR null)
                                    currentPacket, // the next packet to be read into buffer
                                    &numPackets, // number of actually read buffers
                                    _audioQueueBuffer->mAudioData
                                    );
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that Apple doesn't initialise numBytesReadFromFile too. Here is the guide: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/AQPlayback/PlayingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005343-CH3-SW2) Listing 3-4. So can you clarify what Apple means with input and output? Does it mean: first it reads the value stored in numBytesreadFromFile and then it stores a value in numBytesReadFromFile?

Comment: The example you linked to uses `AudioFileReadPackets` which is an older API with different semantics.  With `AudioFileReadPacketData` it is necessary to set `ioNumBytes` to the number of bytes the buffer can hold *before* the function call, and if the function doesn't encounter an error it will replace that value on return with the number of bytes actually read.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice that there was a difference.